# How to fix " please insert the disc labeled Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie"?

Tags: debian

In order to install packages from Synaptic Package Manager , i get an error:

```
please insert the disc labeled
'Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03
```

How to  tell the installer to quit looking for the
DVD to install package from synaptic package manager ?

Answer (score 10):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`

You have something like:

```
#

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64...
```

Comment this line out :

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64...
```

Update your package